# Finding the Bremsstrahlung in diffraction patterns of NaCl

Tags: diffraction, wavelength, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I recently got the chance to measure the diffraction pattern of a NaCl crystal using the Bragg-Brentano method. I can see the peaks caused by the characteristic lines of the used X-ray tube (in this case with a Copper anode). What is also clearly visible is the Bremsstrahlung of the tube.

Now, the diffraction pattern was recorded as a function of the angle $2\theta$. Since the diffraction pattern follows the Bragg condition

$$\lambda=2d\sin{\theta}$$

I thought that I might be able to display the measurements over $\lambda$ by taking all the values from the $\theta$-axis and plugging them into the Bragg condition. It appears to work since the peaks produced by the Copper K$_\alpha$ and K$_\beta$-lines all appear in at the right positions of $\lambda$.
However, I am unable to identify the minimal wavelength of the Bremsstrahlung from the plot.

The X-ray tube was running with a voltage of $U=35$kV, so I expected to see the number of detected X-ray Photons of the diffraction plot to increase rapidly at $\lambda_{min}=\frac{hc}{eU}\approx0.3543$Å. I am indeed able to see a small peak there, but instead of the number of counts per second growing more to resemble the bulge of the Bremsstrahlung as I expected would happen, the number of Photons drops again and stays relatively low until it starts to increase sharply at around $\lambda\approx0.8$Å.
[image: Measurements plotted over Wavelength]

I tried to think about reasons why that could be, but I could not think of anything. Why is there this large gap in the wavelength? Is $\lambda_{min}$ offset to $0.8$Å? Was my assumption about plotting the data over $\lambda$ wrong? I have the feeling that I am missing something rather obvious here.

Comment: What is the specified response of the detector?

Comment: @JonCuster I am not sure. I was given no information about this beyond that it counts incoming X-ray photons, similar to a Geiger counter. Could it be possible that the detector was simply unable to detect the Reflections of the Bremsstrahlung in that Wavelength range?